# Oracle and C#: ORA-01858: A Non-Numeric Character was found

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a tool (C#) that passes SQL queries between applications to integrate data. Most of the time I deal with T-SQL but for this project the source data is in an Oracle DB. I'm filtering the results of my queries based on two parameters, "StartDate" and "EndDate".

When I execute my query in SQL Developer using a literal date instead of the parameters, the query executes fine. However, when my integration tool executes the query using my two date parameters I get the following error: "ORA-01858: A Non-Numeric Character was found where a numeric was expeceted."

Here is the where clause of my query:

```
    WHERE TO_DATE((SUBSTR(PERIOD, 5, 2) || '01' || STARTDATE), 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE(@@ActualStartDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND TO_DATE(@@ActualEndDate, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I have confirmed through other means that my integration tool is passing the date parameter in a "dd/mm/yyyy" format. I have tried setting up my parameter as both a Date and a String (neither work), and I have tried various different date formats in the Where clause.

Can anyone help me pinpoint where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: first of all, I don't know what oracle data provider do you use, but `@@ActualStartDate` substitution vars lools very odd, usually it starts with colon like `:ActualStartDate`. Second, probably you missed `/` char in date concat

Comment: What do `PERIOD` and `STARTDATE` contain, and what data types are they?

Comment: The expression `(SUBSTR(PERIOD, 5, 2) || '01' || STARTDATE)` in  the where clause appears to lack the slashes mandated by the format- have you tried `(SUBSTR(PERIOD, 5, 2) || '/01/' || STARTDATE)` ?

Comment: The @@Parameters are being passed from my external tool, so they must use the '@@' symbol to be picked up. The PERIOD is a string and contains '****01', '****02', etc., each representing a month of the year. Start Date is a number containing a four digit year. I tried adding in the '/' character to my date concatenation but I'm receiving the same error. Thanks.